# solc not producing binary

Tags: solidity, solc

I am trying to compile [OwnedRegistrar](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/registrar/OwnedRegistrar.sol) contract using Solidity. It's like

```
import "./owned.sol";
import "./Registrar.sol";

contract OwnedRegistrar is Registrar, owned {
          // ...
}
```

However `solc` does not produce a binary for this contract nor does it give any error message. Only binary for `owned` contract is given. Am I missing something? Do I need to run a separate link step somewhow? What could be reason for missing binary?

```
[~/code/wattcoin/websauna.wallet/websauna/wallet/ethereum/contracts]% solc ownedregistrar.sol --bin

======= OwnedRegistrar =======
Binary: 


======= Registrar =======
Binary: 


======= owned =======
Binary: 
60606040525b33600060006101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908302179055505b600a80603d6000396000f360606040526008565b00
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some functions from `Registrar` contract were not implemented (mispelt) in `OwnedRegistrar`. Removing these functions from the parent contract hinted `solc` to build a concrete contract and give the code.

I don't still don't know if there is some compiler level way to detect this situation instead of manually going through functions one-by-one.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. Abstract contracts really should be labeled as such